# How to declare list property in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

How do I declare a list property in QML (for use with `Qt.labs.settings` in my case):

```
Settings {
    property list recentFiles: []
}
```

Does not work. I've tried many other options: `list<string>`, `string[]`, etc. None seem to work.

Comment: property variant recentFiles: []

Comment: ["The variant type is a generic property type. It is obsolete and exists only to support old applications; new applications should use var type properties instead."](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-variant.html)

Comment: "A list can only store QML objects, and cannot contain any basic type values. (To store basic types within a list, use the var type instead.)"

Answer (score 15):

```
Settings {
    property var recentFiles: []
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html

Comment: It works, thank you. What is the use of the keyword `list` than?

Answer (score 13):

Since you were asking about the list property (the 'list' keyword), then the following syntax seems to work:

```
property list<Rectangle> rectList: [
    Rectangle { id: a; },
    Rectangle { id: b; }
]

Rectangle { id: c }

Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("length: " + rectList.length)
    rectList.push(c)
    console.log("length: " + rectList.length)
}
```

This will print

```
qml: length: 2
qml: length: 3
```

But I see that 'rectList' would accept also the following:

```
MouseArea { id: mArea; }
..
rectList.push(mArea)
```

Which does not make sense. And command suggestion / auto completion does not work with this syntax in Qt Creator. I guess this is some kind of legacy syntax, which should not be used in new apps. You should use instead what was suggested by other answers:

property var myList: []

Then you get better support by Qt Creator.

And the documentation for 'list' says [1]:

"A list can only store QML objects, and cannot contain any basic type values. (To store basic types within a list, use the var type instead.)"

So the following won't compile:

```
property list<int> intList: []
```

The same docs also say:

"Note: The list type is not recommended as a type for custom properties. The var type should be used instead for this purpose as lists stored by the var type can be manipulated with greater flexibility from within QML."

[1] https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html

Answer (score 9):

> A list can only store QML objects, and cannot contain any basic type
>   values

**string** is a basic type, so you can't store it in list.
For that purpose you'd better use `property var recentFiles`

Comment: As of Qt 6.4 a list now CAN store a value type as well: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.4/qml-list.html

Answer (score 0):

list currently only accepts object types. int is a value type. list should be preferred over var where possible because it is typed.